Setting a folder path and opening a file from set folder in Excel using VBA?
I use a custom built excel workbook (Project Summary) to import time sheet data and break-down the time and cost spent on a project by various team members.
Within the Project Summary I have some macros to import the data from other workbooks and paste it into the current work book.
Below the Macro to import data:
Private Sub refresh()

    ThisWorkbook.Unprotect "Password"
            
    Dim answer As Integer
            
        answer = MsgBox("This action may take a while and will only be avaliable on the Network. Are you sure you want to proceed?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Please Note")
            If answer = vbYes Then
                           
                Call rf01
        
                Call rf02
        
                Call rf03
        
                Call rf04
        
                Call rf05
        
                Call rf06
        
                Call rf07
        
                Call rf08
        
                Call rf09
                
                Call rf10
        
            Else
                End If
        
    Sheets("Welcome").Select
    
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1:O24").Select
            ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
            ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Select
            
    Sheets("Welcome").Select
    
    ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="Password", Structure:=True, Windows:=True

End Sub

I use a different version of the code below for each of the 10 users to import the specific data.
Private Sub rf01()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Dim wb0 As Workbook
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    
    Dim strname1 As String
    strname1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calc 01").Range("L5").Value
    
    Set wb0 = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("\\IP Address\folder\folder\01 - User1 - Time Sheet.xlsx", True, True", True, True)
            wb1.Activate
            Sheets("Time Sheet").Select
                Worksheets("Time Sheet").Unprotect "Password"
            
            Worksheets("Time Sheet").Select
            ActiveSheet.Range("A9").Select
            Worksheets("Time Sheet").AutoFilterMode = False
                Worksheets("Time Sheet").Range("A8").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & strname1 & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
                    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Copy
            
            wb0.Activate
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TS 01").Range("A7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                
                ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Select
            
            wb1.Close False, False
            
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TS 01").Visible = xlVeryHidden
        
End Sub

At the moment this can only be done when a user is on-site and has access to our NAS server. Our NAS sync's to OneDrive, thus it should be possible to run the code while not on-site.
The problem I'm having is that the directory where the Time Sheet workbooks is stored will vary from user to user.
How would I go about prompting the person that wants to compile the report to specify the folder on their local system / OneDrive, and then import the data from the Time Sheet Workbooks?
The Time sheet workbooks has the following naming convention:
usernumber - username.xlsx
I am not that proficient in VBA coding. Most all of the coding was cobbled together from various forums, websites and YouTube tutorials.
If it's stupid but it works...

I believe this is what you're looking for, at least to have the user select a folder locally. I don't use OneDrive so I don't know if/how it works with it.

I assume you have 20 sheets TS 01,Calc 01,TS 02,Calc 02 etc for the 10 names
Option Explicit

Private Sub refresh()

    Dim fso As Object, oFolder As Object, colFiles As Collection
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim f, i As Long, msg As String, sFilename As String
    Set colFiles = New Collection
    
    ' choose folder
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select a folder"
        .Show
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "You did not select a folder", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set oFolder = fso.getFolder(.SelectedItems(1))
    End With
    
    ' build collection of files that match pattern
    For Each f In oFolder.Files
        ' filename is NN - name - Timesheet.xlsx
        If f.Name Like "##*-*.xlsx" Then
            'Debug.Print f.Path
            colFiles.Add f, CStr(f.Path)
        End If
    Next
    
    ' user check
    If colFiles.Count > 0 Then
        msg = colFiles.Count & " workbooks found in " & _
              oFolder.Path & ", do you want to continue ?"
        If vbNo = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo) Then Exit Sub
    Else
        msg = "No workbooks found"
        MsgBox msg, vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' process workbooks
    Dim wb As Workbook, rngTo As Range, sNo As String, sName As String
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    wb.Unprotect Password:="Password"
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each f In colFiles
        ' filename is NN - name - Timesheet.xlsx
        sNo = Left(f.Name, 2)
        If sNo >= 1 And sNo <= 10 Then
            sName = wb.Sheets("Calc " & sNo).Range("L5").Value
            Set rngTo = wb.Sheets("TS " & sNo).Range("A7")
            Call rf(f, sName, rngTo)
        Else
            MsgBox f.Name & " not valid file", vbExclamation
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    With wb.Sheets("Welcome")
        .Activate
        .Range("A1:O24").Select
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
        .Range("B7").Select
    End With
      
    'ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="Password", Structure:=True, Windows:=True
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TS 01").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    MsgBox "Process complete"

End Sub

Private Sub rf(f, sName As String, rngTo As Range)

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(f.Path, True, True, True, True)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Time Sheet")
    With ws

        .Unprotect "Password"
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A8").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & sName & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Copy
        
        rngTo.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False ' clear Clipbaord
        .Range("A2").Select
        
    End With
    wb.Close False, False
    rngTo.Select
            
End Sub

